# Publish .NET 6 test coverage - GitLab CI

Tags: .net, shell, gitlab-ci, test-coverage

I'm setting up a pipeline for .NET 6 project on GitLab.
I run the test, then generate the code coverage report in the `coverage.cobertura.xml` file.
Here is the test job script:

```
test:
  only:
    - master
    - /^feature/.*$/
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build-application
  variables:
    CONFIGURATION: "Debug"
    COVERAGE_FLAG: "XPlat Code Coverage"
    LOGGER_FLAG: "junit;LogFilePath=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit/junit-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
    TEST_PROJECTS: "./tests/*Tests/*.csproj"
  script:
    - 'dotnet test $TEST_PROJECTS
            -c $CONFIGURATION
            -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura
            --collect:"$COVERAGE_FLAG"
            --test-adapter-path:.
            --logger:"$LOGGER_FLAG"'
    - chmod +x ./scripts/print-dotnet-coverage.sh
    - ./scripts/print-dotnet-coverage.sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura
  coverage: /TOTAL_COVERAGE=(\d+.\d+)/
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura/*/coverage.cobertura.xml
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit/junit-test-result.xml
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/cobertura/*/coverage.cobertura.xml
      junit:
        - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit/junit-test-result.xml
```

The pain is the test command doesn't produce any output concerning the total coverage percentage, so I extract it from the newly created `coverage.cobertura.xml` file and print it to stdout using the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
REPORTS_DIR="${1}"
coverage=0
count=0
for i in $(find "$REPORTS_DIR" -name '*.xml');
do
    printf "Found coverage report: %s\n" "$i"
    coverage="$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/coverage/@line-rate)' ${i})"
    count=$((count + 1))
done;
printf "Found a total of %i report(s)\n" "$count"
coverage=$(echo "$coverage * 100" | bc) <-- error here
printf "TOTAL_COVERAGE=%2.4f\n" "$(echo "${coverage}")"
```

Because the coverage percentage is 0.8875, I have to multiply it by 100. But I got an error

```
./scripts/print-dotnet-coverage.sh: 12: bc: not found
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error or how to achieve my purpose - multiply the coverage by 100 in GitLab CI - without using bc?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you `apt-get install bc`? Looks as if you are using the following tutorial published November 2021: https://medium.com/tuimm/net-code-coverage-on-gitlab-3e35f08d0f44

Comment: It doesn't work. But I follow Richard's answer, he does it in a different way and it works perfecttly for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following example project for setting up code coverage reporting: [dotnet-example](https://gitlab.com/radavis/dotnet-example)

- [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/radavis/dotnet-example/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)
- [test job output](https://gitlab.com/radavis/dotnet-example/-/jobs/2575798172)

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly simpler solution that doesn't require the report generator, you can get coverlet to also output in the opencover format which already includes the total coverage as a percentage.

```
test:
  stage: test
  coverage: /sequenceCoverage=\"\d+(?:\.\d+)?\"/
  script:
    - dotnet test Project --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage;Format=cobertura,opencover"
    - grep "Summary" -r -h -m 1 Project/TestResults/*/coverage.opencover.xml
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: "Project/TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml"
```